# template ruby string-eval bug?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

In the following A and B should be equivalent but only version A works.  The rails string evaluation seems broken or occurring too early/late or something.  Any ideas?

```
<% content_for :main do %>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){

    //$("#users-new").dialog();          //A

    $(<%= "\"#users-new\"" %>).dialog();  //B

  });

</script>

<div  id="users-new">
  testing
</div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: And the really strange thing is, the following works, though it shouldn't:   $(<%= "users-new" %>).dialog();

Comment: or rather it works intermittently - truly bizarre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails3+ HTML encodes the content in `<%= ... %>`by default. That means that your **B** comes out like this:

```
$(&quot;#users-new&quot;).dialog();
```

and that makes no sense in JavaScript. You want one of these:

```
$(<%= raw "\"#users-new\"" %>).dialog();
$(<%= "\"#users-new\"".html_safe %>).dialog();
```

Either of those will give you the JavaScript that you're expecting:

```
$("#users-new").dialog();
```

Comment: ...neither did the second version

Comment: @Mark: What does "not work" mean? Have you looked at the page's source?

Comment: OK now both version are working but that doesn't mean anything yet, because neither did just a second ago, and as I mentioned above,  $(<%= "users-new" %>).dialog() worked as well once, though it shouldn't, and then stopped working.

Comment: @Mark: You have a caching problem somewhere. Use your browser's *View Source* to look at the generated page when it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, they are both working consisently now.  Don't know why it didn't work initially - maybe there's some delayed propogation of something in rails somewhere (using test server).  I'll come back and mark this as answered if I don't have any more problems.  Thanks a lot.